# Visual Studio 2019 suddenly requires nuget Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk to run xUnit unit-tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nuget, xunit

I'm using xUnit for implementing tests. I used to install the xUnit Visual Studio runner, `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget package to run tests using the VS GUI.

Below is are xUnit-related branches of the dependency tree in VS. You can clearly see the xUnit VS runner has no dependencies:

[image: xUnit dependencies for a net472 project]

Visual Studio is suddenly asking me to install the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` nuget in order to run tests in the GUI. Anyone knows why?

Note:

- I have been using VS 2019 for over a year frequently updating asap. The problem occurred only yesterday. I'm on v16.7.2 now.

Comment: Probably because xunit runner for VS requires it?

Comment: It's been working without it for years. No changes in code or dependencies were introduced, only updates of VS itself.

Comment: Did you install the `xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1`? If not, you should update the package to use `2.4.1` version.

Comment: Also, what is your old vs version and did it a `net core 3.1` project?

Comment: Yes. I have `xunit.runner.visualstudio` v2.4.1. The project is a .net framework project

Comment: Actually, there is a xunit project template in VS2019 and the default template contains the nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`. Besides, the mainstream xunit projects are all based on `net core` rather than `net framework`. Also, I wonder what is your previous vs version. Perhaps there is a big gap between them. Since the latest VS IDE, it actually require that nuget package and your project is net framework, the nuget `xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1` will not install that dependency `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` unless your project is based on `net core` . So the error arises.

Comment: The latest VS2019 needs that package and the default project template contains that. Also, please try to create a new net core xunit test projest in VS2019 and you can migrate your old project into the new one to get the latest,easy way to avoid this. Besides, I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the difference between `xunit.runner.visualstudio` for various target frameworks. Though not answering the question. I assures me I had no missing dependencies the whole time. I think it's VS, which started to ask for it explicitly.

Comment: Actually, vs has required this nuget package on the latest version. For your updated issue, enter your csproj file, change your target framework to `netcoreapp3.1`. Use like this `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`. Then rebuild your project, I think you will see the dependency under it.

Comment: Or not change the target framework and then  directly install that required nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` directly. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**During** [xunit.runner.visualstudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/2.4.1) version <=`2.4.1`, it already contains a dependency `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, and the later version `2.4.2` and `2.4.3` has removed such dependency `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`.

also, not sure whether the issue is caused by the update of VS which requires such package recently. And from the default `xunit` template project, it contains the package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` by default. **So I think VS requires this package.**

Maybe in some specific cases, no error will be reported without this package, but there will be no accidental errors in the follow-up, so install this package.

**Besides**, not sure whether you have install the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` version <= `2.4.1` which already has such package, and then update this package later during the VS Update.

**Suggestion**

**1)**, try to reinstall `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget package, first uninstall it and then install the version `2.4.1`.

**Then**, close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder.

**2)** try to change the target framework version of your project(it will install any default nuget packages based on the target framework version).

Right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Application**--> change **target framework** to anyone else first and then change it back to the original one.

[image]

**In addition**, if these do not work, you should share a sample of your project with us and provide more detailed info so that it will help us troubleshoot the issue more quickly.

**Update 1**

For your updated issue, or you could install the nuget package [Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/) directly on your project.

Or change your project target framework to `net core`.

**Use** this in csproj file:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

**Then**, rebuild your project and you can see the dependency under it.

Comment: This should be marked as accepted, adding the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` did the trick for me.

Comment: I had tried installing the package as the error suggests doing, but that did not help. Changing the target framework did the trick, though. Thank you so much!